# Use of bodyless function

Tags: php, codeception

I've been digging through codeception source and found this piece of code I don't understand:

```
<?php
namespace Codeception\Lib\Actor\Shared;

use Codeception\Scenario;

trait Comment
{
    /**
     * @return Scenario
     */
    abstract protected function getScenario();

    // OTHER CODE

    public function comment($description)
    {
        $this->getScenario()->comment($description);
        return $this;
    }
}
```

I have two questions:

1. What does the use of bodyless `getScenario()` mean?
2. What does the line `$this->getScenario()->comment($description);`
   inside `comment` method mean?

I'd appreciate a vague explanation of what is happening in the code, Thank you.

Comment: The [PHP Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php) is always a good starting point - When that trait is used in a class, the class ___must___ implement that method.... that's what "__abstract__" means

Comment: That's the point, I see that `getScenario` is just declared, not implemented, but it's still being used. Can you, please, explain in more depth?

Comment: It can ___only___ be used when that trait is __used__ in a class; and any class that uses it ___must___ implement a `abstract protected function getScenario()` method.... this `abstract` is the trait's way of telling classes "if you want to use me, then you must include an implementation of this method.... and if you don't, I'll scream horrible messages to you"

Comment: As for the second question: `$this->getScenario()->comment($description);`.... when the comment() method is called in a class that uses this trait, it calls the `getScenario()` method that's implemented in that class, and which returns an object with a `comment()` method that is then called,

Comment: Excellent, thank you! Would you mind to post an answer so I could accept it?